C# Colocar imagenes dentro del cuerpo del correo
Estoy haciendo una función en c# para envío de correos y quiero que en el body del correo quede pegada una imagen como parte del mensaje, ya he revisado en varias partes y finalmente pude hacerlo pero al enviar el correo envío un adjunto de un pdf pero sale automaticamente otro archivo adjunto que tiene que ver con la imagen, hay alguna manera que se pueda colocar esa imagen sin que adjunte automaticamente ese archivo?
Este es el codigo:
MailMessage eMail = new MailMessage();
                eMail.From = new MailAddress("pruebaclinica2024@outlook.com", "Clinica");
                eMail.To.Add(new MailAddress("destinatario.prueba@outlook.com"));
                eMail.Subject = "ejemplo definitivo";
                string imagePathF = @"E:\Ejemplo.jpg";
                LinkedResource idimage = new LinkedResource(imagePathF);
                idimage.ContentId = "naranjas";
                string textoEmail = "<h2>Hola, este es un correo de prueba:</h2>";
                AlternateView htmlView =
                AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<html><body><img src='cid:naranjas'> <br/>"+ textoEmail + "</body></html>", null, "text/html");
                eMail.BodyEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
                htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(idimage);
                eMail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
                System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(Mensaje);
                eMail.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
                client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("pruebaclinica2024@outlook.com", "naranjas");
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Send(eMail);  

Y este es el resultado,les agradezco cualquier sugerencia la idea es que la imagen azul este en el cuerpo pero que no salga en el adjunto el archivo ATT00001.bin.


Te recomiendo usar un archivo .HTM independiente para generar el correo, aqui lo disenas en cualquier editor por ejemplo Sublime Text y lo llamas desde tu codigo, para pasarle informacion puedes usar parametros @_Parametro1, @_parametro2 etc para llenar el correo de informacion. en tu caso cuando el correo quiera ser mas grande modificarlo desde el codigo muchas veces es muy tedioso, de igual forma si solo lo quieres para adjuntar archivos es funcional.

Finalmente, mirando en un video de youtube y comparando ese código con el mio  descubrí que me faltaba un parámetro  MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg en varios ejemplos que vi en otros sitios no los colocaban, le coloque ese parámetro y ya me envía correctamente el correo  sin ese archivo adjunto adicional.
LinkedResource idimage = new LinkedResource(imagePathF, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);



Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
